# how to Stream a youtube video in php?

Tags: php, youtube

There is site which gets direct link to youtube server as for example if we visit the link

http://vimow.com/watch?v=TLM6e_slo7Q-Play-Xbox-in-a-WEB-BROWSER?---Inside-Gaming-Daily

now if we view the page source will notice that there is the following link in video src

https://r5---sn-npo7enel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?mt=1410551258&expire=1410572981&ratebypass=yes&key=yt5&signature=C3FB417A7FB4C61600553152F9FFB57E473C762B.8F451B015AF741FFE45777DB5CEF424E452D433F&fexp=914095%2C927622%2C931983%2C932404%2C934030%2C946023%2C947209%2C948205%2C953600%2C953801%2C955400&upn=nnZKYWtq7gU&pfa=20s&initcwndbps=12869000&id=o-AMzBGT7otDdEr3LZCZRZA1hv1-ovI_PTghQHLJWtmAGq&ipbits=0&source=youtube&ms=au&pm_type=static&pbr=yes&mm=31&ip=128.199.133.159&sver=3&mv=m&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpbr%2Cpfa%2Cpm_type%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&itag=18

my question is that how they are getting that link from youtube ?

i searched youtube api but did not find any solution.

Comment: Yeah I'm hell lot searching this. This is all cipher stuff. I can't understand!

Answer (score 2):

I've messaged you about your query. Check once. Since its not allowed as in terms of YouTube ToS, I can't disclose the method publically.

Comment: Could you contact me too?

Comment: @user2513722 I'm also in need of that.. thank you bro

Comment: @MehulMohan I have been searching for this scripts for weeks and I had no luck yet. Please help me on this... Thanks

Comment: I also realy need this info... can you contact me please??

Answer (score 1):

got o youtube choose your video and click share after that click include (or something like that i can see it in french soo..) it will genereate a link like this one embed it in your page :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YoB8t0B4jx4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

or you can just make it (the iframe adding the url of the video look at src of the iframe abouve

Answer (score 1):

These movies are placed on Google Drive, and the link comes from there. See:

http://drive.google.com

For sharing details see:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&ref_topic=2525251

So, no, they're not from Youtube. There are API's for Google drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/

For PHP see:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

You'll have to familiarize yourself with this API before you can use it. The documentation by Google is far more than I could provide here.

Comment: But still, how is it working? I cannot find any API to get youtube video uploaded to Google Drive and then get back its link via backend only. If you look closely, the watch?v= parameter on both the sites is same and is similarly handled for same videos for vimow as well. Can you explain that?

Comment: I've added two links to the Google Drive API.

Comment: I see you've answered your own question. Regrettably it is not very clear.

Comment: Well @KIKO Software According to Youtube, they offer no API to get direct links for their videos, its not permitted in their ToS as well. So how is the above site fetching them? I'm pretty sure they are not using any official API.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution for this problem.
Youtube videos are hosted in google's server.
So we need to find the root link  to the video and we can just stream the video using any HTML player.
This is example of a link

> https://r3---sn-npo7enee.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&ip=128.199.175.59&initcwndbps=15683750&id=o-AOiPqW3plUekS9E0iFfUXJ6M6iuK8dAdvw0rtzBvFIMf&key=yt5&mm=31&ipbits=0&mt=1411445657&itag=18&sver=3&fexp=927622,930666,931983,932404,934030,936216,946023,947209,949408,952302,953801&upn=W8Os8snP-z8&sparams=id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1411467316&ratebypass=yes&signature=0F620B35EBCD3796509B9F72DC0EA15384721857.734B6A96DB834E600CEFBEF9305AA30E3F051A66

So i hope after getting this link you can easily stream a youtube video.
You can use youtube downloader which fetches the link using CURL.
A good script on github

> https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader

Using the script if you input the video id portion of any youtube video.
Example: youtube(dot)com/watch?v=**Fw-BM-Mqgeg**

It uses curl to fetch the video link and u can use the link to stream video in your site.

Comment: Anybody can download that video, and play it back, your question was how they got the link. You don't seem to answer your own question?

Comment: I tried this script. It doesn't returned docs.google type URL. It returns googlevideo.com url...

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is a link in Google Drive. It has nothing to do with YouTube.

On another hand, if you're looking to embed YouTube videos in your website, then this will help you: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

If you want to stream a video while it occurs ("live streaming" or live coverage), then you need to use a special server which supports live streaming:

- You can use the YouTube Live API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/
- You can use LiveSteam: http://new.livestream.com/
- and there's many other streaming services

Keep in mind that you need a videocam which supports streaming services, or you should link the videocam to your computer. It depends on the streaming service you're using.